# Smoke Wisps in Blender 3.5

Tags: smoke-simulation, blenderkit

How can I make thin smoke wisps in Blender 3.5? Please share the procedure. Here is a reference. [image]

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck? This site isn't meant for full tutorials :)